# Changing the name of the key of a dict comprising RDFlib terms

Tags: python, dictionary, linked-data, rdflib

A variant of this question has been asked in the past. However, I wasn't able to get the responses working for me. This is a sample dict I have:

```
{rdflib.term.URIRef(u'<http://purl.org/net/ontology#isGivenDrugA>'): rdflib.term.Literal(u'<http://purl.org/net/ontology#dose1>')}
{rdflib.term.URIRef(u'<http://purl.org/net/ontology#isGivenDrugB>'): rdflib.term.Literal(u'<http://purl.org/net/ontology#dose2>')}
{rdflib.term.URIRef(u'<http://purl.org/net/ontology#isGivenDrugC>'): rdflib.term.Literal(u'<http://purl.org/net/ontology#dose3>')}
```

I want to rename the first term in each of the dicts to `isNotGivenDrugA` or B or C. For instance:

```
{rdflib.term.URIRef(u'<http://purl.org/net/ontology#isNotGivenDrugA>'): rdflib.term.Literal(u'<http://purl.org/net/ontology#dose1>')}
```

How can I do so?

This is the code I have so far:

```
for s in notGivenDrugList:
        print ('s: ',s)
        for k,v in s.iteritems():
            print k
```

`k` gives me the first term of each dict. If I assign it a value based on `k.replace`, that doesn't work as keys of dict are immutable and `iteritems` only creates copies of the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You will need to recreate the dictionary items with the desired key.

Comment: I understand that bit (hence the reference to immutability of the keys in the question). The problem is, I wouldn't know all the elements of the list as the data is being parsed from a database.

What is an elegant way to program this?

Comment: There isn't one. You'd have to load the database and then process the data afterwards.